# Notificação de usuário para usuário em diferentes apps

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notification

Eu estava fazendo alguns estudos relacionados ao desenvolvimento do Android, e me deparei com a seguinte questão. Como posso enviar uma notificação de um usuário em um aplicativo para outro em outro aplicativo.

Exemplo:

Um usuário em um aplicativo de compras faz um pedido, como o envio da notificação desse pedido ao comerciante usando o aplicativo feito para venda? Quais ferramentas devo usar?

Comment: Utilize Firebase Notification, OneSignal, Pusher etc

Comment: Você pode utilizar um serviço de plataforma, tem o Firebase Notification, eu tbm uso o Backendless que é muito eficiente https://backendless.com/